# When tmux enters copy mode, is there a relative line number as Vim does?

Tags: linux, shell, tmux

For me , the most helpful vim trick is the relative line number, which can help me to randomly access a line

Is there a similar facility in tmux when I enter copy mode? If I can randomly access a location, I guess I can finally decommission my mouse

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32786033/4635198).

When in copy-mode, `:`, then `g` , which enters `(goto line)` mode, then type in your line number, e.g., `42`.

N.B. Line 0 is the last-line of the buffer (bottom).